# problem on schwarz reflection principle

Tags: complex-analysis

let f be an entire function on $\mathbb C$.Let g(z)=$\overline{f(\bar z)}$. Then which of the following are true:

(1)If f(z)$\in \mathbb R $  $\forall z\in \mathbb R$,then,f(z)=g(z)

(2)if f(z)$\in \mathbb R $  $\forall z\in [z:im(z)=0] \cup [z:im(z)=a]$ for some a$\gt$0, then , f(z-ia)=f(z+ia) $\forall z\in\mathbb C$

(3)if f(z)$\in \mathbb R $  $\forall z\in [z:im(z)=0] \cup [z:im(z)=a]$ for some a$\gt$0,then, f(z+2ia)=f(z) $\forall z\in\mathbb C$

(4)if f(z)$\in \mathbb R $  $\forall z\in [z:im(z)=0] \cup [z:im(z)=a]$ for some a$\gt$0,then, f(z+ia)=f(z) $\forall z\in\mathbb C$

i think that schwarz reflection principle might help out,but,i have no idea on how to apply it and proceed in this question

any help would be appreciated..

Comment: for (2) how would you use the [Schwarz reflection principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_reflection_principle) only from $f(z)$ is analytic on $Im(z) > -\epsilon$ and $f(z) \in \mathbb{R}$ for $Im(z) = 0$ ?

Comment: @user1952009:thanks for suggestion...i see that reflection priciple cannot be applied...please suggest some other way if possible..

Comment: why do you think it can't ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_reflection_principle